# Capturing Customer's e-Signature inside docusign embedded elastic template?

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to capture customer's signature inside the document generated from elastic template? The advantage of elastic template over regular template is embedding inside the Iframe so that the document is visible inside the app screen. But can we capture the eSignature!!??

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently available, but will be in a few months. At the moment - you cannot do this with elastic templates.